# As a C# developer, how do I find out whether a DLL method needs to be P/Invoked with stdcall or with cdecl calling convention?

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke, dllimport

Consider the following two (randomly chosen, just because I happen to use both of them in the project that I have currently open) example API calls, both contained in Microsoft libraries:

- [LocalDBCreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/express-localdb-instance-apis/localdbcreateinstance-function?view=sql-server-ver16)
- [OpenPrinter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/openprinter)

The first one needs `CallingConvention.Cdecl` when P/Invoked through the `DLLImport` attribute, the second one needs the default value `WinApi`/`StdCall`.

Currently, I use one of the following techniques to find out which one to use:

1. **Guess**: If it's built-in Windows API, it's probably StdCall, otherwise it's probably Cdecl.
2. **Research**: Find the SDK containing the header file, install the SDK, search my whole hard drive to find that header file buried somewhere deep inside some obscure folder, and then look inside and check the function declaration.

Is there an easier way? For example, is there some reliable way to deduce the calling convention from the MSDN documentation link of the API method (see the two examples above)?

Comment: look at the c header files

Comment: @DanielA.White: Since this is exactly what I mentioned in point 2, I don't quite see yet how that qualifies as "an easier way".

Comment: Go to https://www.pinvoke.net/ and see if if your method's PInvoke signature is given there.  Many are, for instance https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winspool/OpenPrinter.html is shown.   No result for [`LocalDBCreateInstance`](https://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=LocalDBCreateInstance&namespace=[All]) though.

Comment: I am of the belief that making `LocalDBCreateInstance` cdecl was a mistake, one they secretly would like to take back but can't because it's out there. Microsoft exports functions with the stdcall convention for the compatibility with the broadest set of languages. Complicating the matter is the fact that it returns `HRESULT`, a COM-related type, and COM functions are stdcall, so it's pretending to be a COM-like function. When in doubt, try stdcall first. If the stack gets corrupted and you get an exception, it's cdecl; switch to that.

Comment: It's been a while, but I don't think cdecl functions can be exported with bare names. If it's marked `extern "C"`, I believe it'll still have an underscore prefix and the compiler will treat it like any "C" function. If it's a C++ function, it'll be name-mangled. Try dumping the DLL's exported symbols and see how it's actually exported. If you see a lot of non-alphanumeric stuff, especially multiple "`@`" characters, that has to be cdecl. It's unclear, though, if that's "easy" enough for you.

Comment: This may not be helpful is many cases, but I often find [Sourcegraph.com](https://sourcegraph.com/search) to be useful. For example, I searched on "LocalDBCreateInstance" for your first example, and in 2.23 seconds was shown results where I could clearly see it requires `cdecl`.

Comment: Don't look at pinvoke.net it's full of mistakes. Look at the header files. End of story.

Comment: For "most" of Windows API, you can use this Microsoft-provided "metadata" https://github.com/microsoft/win32metadata. It's DllImport declaration for `Windows.Win32.Graphics.Printing.Apis.OpenPrinterW` will be implicit (so stdcall) `[DllImport("winspool.drv", ExactSpelling = true, PreserveSig = false, SetLastError = true)] public unsafe static extern BOOL OpenPrinterW([In] [Optional] PWSTR pPrinterName, [Out] HANDLE* phPrinter, [In] [Optional] PRINTER_DEFAULTSW* pDefault);` Unfortunatey, LocalDBCreateInstance is not in the Windows SDK so it's not defined by these Win32Metadata definitions.

Comment: And here's the C#/Win32 P/Invoke Source Generator associated tool https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32 based on it.

Comment: Thanks for all the great comments! Unless someone else wants to do it, I'll wait a few days and then summarize all the "tips and tricks" in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the header files **is** the right thing to do.

**Step 1**: Find out which header file you need. Both examples you mentioned have information about the required header file on their documentation page (msoledbsql.h and Winspool.h, respectively).

**Step 2**: Get the header file. You can do this by installing the SDK containing the header file, but, as you point out in your question, it can be a hassle to find the SDK, download it, find its installation location, etc.

However, chances are that you are not the first one to use that API method and that the header file can be found in a public repository. Querying [Sourcegraph](https://sourcegraph.com/search), for example, for `LocalDBCreateInstance msoledbsql.h` and `OpenPrinterW file:winspool\.h$` will yield the relevant information as the very first result.

```
HRESULT __cdecl LocalDBCreateInstance(PCWSTR wszVersion, PCWSTR pInstanceName, DWORD dwFlags)
```

```
BOOL WINAPI OpenPrinterW(LPWSTR pPrinterName, LPHANDLE phPrinter, LPPRINTER_DEFAULTSW pDefault);
```

---

Other alternatives for C# developers include:

- Download the [Win32 metadata](https://github.com/microsoft/win32metadata) file and find the correct C# DllImport specification with ILSpy.
- Use the [C#/Win32 P/Invoke Source Generator](https://github.com/microsoft/cswin32) to auto-generate Windows API declarations in your code.

Those are official Microsoft projects, so the information is likely to be accurate. Note, though, that they will work only for built-in Windows API methods (so they would help with OpenPrinter but not with LocalDBCreateInstance).

<sub>*(Kudos to @The2Step and @Simon Mourier for teaching me about Sourcegraph and win32metadata/CsWin32 in the comments.)*</sub>